# Are these MySQL indexes duplicates?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I'm a little confused on the best indexing options for this table. I will want to do searching and joining on both ServiceID and TagID. I also need to make sure the two combined are unique.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `service-tag` (
  `ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ServiceID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `TagID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ServiceID` (`ServiceID`,`TagID`),
  KEY `TagID` (`TagID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=39 ;
```

Is adding the second index on TagID necessary or does it automatically get indexed properly just from being the 2nd column in the UNIQUE index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a multi-column index (as the `ServiceID` index IS) then MySQL cannot use that index when you're only searching on say `TagID`. In lay-language, MySQL cannot "reach" into the index w/o using `ServiceID` when you only need `TagID`.

Thus, if you do plan on only using `TagID` in a statement than you would want to keep that index.

If you never plan on only querying on `TagID` and all of your queries will always use both `ServiceID` and `TagID`, then yes, the `TagID`-only index is not needed.

This behavior is documented in the manual:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html

> If the table has a multiple-column index, any leftmost prefix of the index can be used by the optimizer to look up rows. For example, if you have a three-column index on (col1, col2, col3), you have indexed search capabilities on (col1), (col1, col2), and (col1, col2, col3).
>
> MySQL cannot use the index to perform lookups if the columns do not form a leftmost prefix of the index.